PWA With Push Notifications
I have been using a PWA Mobile web app for my website for years now.
I want to add a way for users to accept push notifications, while my PWA is already active.
Is this possible? All of the examples I see seem to Install the service worker after the Push Notifications are granted which allows the service worker "active" to fire, which saves the push notification subscriber.
Here's a small example
script.js
Notification.requestPermission()

service worker.js
self.addEventListener("activate", async (e) => {
     await self.registration.pushManager.subscribe({
          userVisibleOnly: true,
          applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array("key")
     }).then((subscription) => {
         return saveSubscription(subscription);

     }).then((response) => {

         console.log(response);

     }).catch((error) => {

         console.log("ERROR");

         console.log(error);

     });
})

But because my service worker is already installed, once I send Notification.requestPermission(); it's not firing the "active" event in the service worker.
How can I save the push notification subscribers after they accept the push notifications?
Without re-saving it over and over or using additional cookies to stop the re-saving?
I have tried things like:
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
     if (permission !== 'granted') {
          return error(permission);
     }
        `{activate function - undefined }`
});

What is the best way to do this?
By calling navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js");' again..  I don't see any 'activate' being fired..
The only way I seem to be able to get subscribers who have accepted notifications is by updating my service worker,, and waiting for the browser to update.. thus calling 'activate' again and sending me the subscriber information.
Any help would be awesome! I been trying to get this thing to pick up the communication for a few days now and I don't want to overcomplicate it.
What is the best practice for this?
The only idea I can think of next is to make a way for the script.js to communicate with service worker.js so that I can tell service worker.js to "Save Subscription" like this:
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
         if (permission !== 'granted') {
              return error(permission);
         }
         sendtoserviceworker('save subscription!');
    });

But I hope there is an easier solution? Thank you for any help!!

Why do you need to save the subscription in the SW? Why can't you just do it normally in script.js? (If you really need to do it in the SW, message passing is the way to go)
